# HTML table border issue in nested table

Tags: html, css

I have nested table. Both tables needs border. The only difference is that I need only the bottom border of the inner table rather having top, bottom, right and left. I need the default border style which comes using the following code.

```
<table border="1">
```

Problem comes when I use this code for the inner table. It sets the outer border too rather setting bottom border. If I remove top right and left border it does not remove the border correctly. Please check the following code which I used to fix this issue.

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
        <td valign="top">VMware Certified Professional</td>
        <td style="padding:0px;">
            <table border="1">
                <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
                <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
                <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
                <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
            </table>             
        </td>            
   </tr>                        
   <tr>
        <td valign="top">VMware Certified Associate</td>
        <td style="padding:0px;">
            <table border="1">
                <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
                <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
                <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
                <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
            </table>             
        </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Screenshot is attached to show default border style which I need.

[image]

Attached is the layout which I want

[image]

Comment: Just use CSS. For example, `border-bottom`.

Comment: I need the default border style. I do not need border:1px solid #000 type style.

Comment: Still, it's good practice to use CSS instead: http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa121597_2.htm

Comment: The screenshot has a border on all sides of the inner tables. So what do you really want?

Comment: I have attached the layout which I want. I do not want solid table border rather i want the default table border style.

Comment: It seems that what you want is rather different from what the question says. Please consider deleting this and posting a new question that explains what you really want. Probably the key is the picture that you have now added. You seem to mean that inner tables should have no borders but they should have borders between their cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going trough many solutions. I found the following solution good for me.

```
 <style>
   .tbl_head{ width:35%;}
</style>
<table cellpadding="3" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
  <td rowspan="3" valign="top" class="tbl_head">ALIGNVALIGNALIGN</td>
  <td>First</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Second</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Third</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="3" valign="top" class="tbl_head">VALIGNALIGNVALIGN</td>
  <td>First</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>Second</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Third</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two inner tables, and assuming that “I need only the bottom border of the inner table rather having top, bottom, right and left” refers to both of them, just set the borders you don’t want to `none` as follows (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yucca42/D496z/)):

```
<style>
table table {
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
</style>
```

An alternative, pure HTML way (which works well, despite being flagged “deprecated” in HTML 4 and “obsolete” in HTML5) is to use the attribute `frame="below"` in the inner `<table>` elements. See [alternative jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yucca42/kH4N7/).

The results look odd, though, and maybe you meant to ask something different.

Comment: @aishazafar, what is not working for you: how does the rendering differ from the expected, on which browser(s)?

Comment: Above code does not work for me correctly. It does not remove border from left, right and top correctly.

Comment: @aishazafar, both of the solutions I posted remove those borders around the inner tables. If you think otherwise, you are probably mistaking *cell* borders for table borders.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/5Ax52/1/

Using CSS:

```
table.inner td {
    border-top: 1px solid #444;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #afafaf;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: This sets borders on inner table *cells*, not on the *table* as requested for. Besides, those borders are not in the default border style.

Comment: Jukka - The only way to draw a partial border is with CSS, and in order to draw it on the bottom of the cells as you requested, it has to be defined for the TD element. @Vecta's example gives you probably the closest approximation to the HTML-style border you'll get for a partial-border. CSS border styles can only be defined one edge at a time (thus 1 color per edge), so using the default cell padding, the top & bottom border of adjacent cells visually look like the HTML style border.

Comment: *Who* requested a border on *cells*? The question refers to “the bottom border of the inner table”.